# disabling line breaks in datatool table

Tags: tables, line-breaking, database

I have a csv file containing a list of names with addresses. I'm using the `datatool` package to load these and output stickers (using the `labels` package) for envelopes. This is done using `\DTLforeach`. Sometimes a name is too long for one line so I manually include a `\\` in the csv as to not hyphenate a name.

I also want to print a complete list of all recipients using `\DTLdisplaydb`.

For my stickers this works very well, but of course this breaks my table listing all recipients.

As an MWE, save this as data.csv:

```
Name,Street,City
John Doe,Street 1,A City
Osop Eskobmr Sempeg Cotbadt\\Demnoskoywar,Street 9,B City
Jeeta Ex,Street 2,A City
```

and use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{labels}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{address}{data.csv}
\DTLforeach{address}{\name=Name,\street=Street,\city=City}%
{\addresslabel{\name\\ \street\\ \city}}

\DTLdisplaydb{address}
\end{document}
```

I guess I could insert a special command like `\mybreak` and define it as empty or as `\newline` depending on the situation. But I would prefer to keep the data as is.

Comment: This is a common programming problem with addresses and databases one way out of it, is to define additional fields, i.e. name, addressi, addressii, city etc. I would avoid any presentational info in a DB like the plague. I am not sure if that is what you are looking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\addresslabel` typesets its argument ragged right (using `\raggedright`) in a box of the appropriate width. Since `\raggedright` almost never hyphenates, this is most likely sufficient. When I remove the `\\` from your example, I get the behavior I believe you want.

One way to ensure you don't get any hyphenation is to add `\lefthyphenmin1000` as an optional argument to `\addresslabel`:

```
\addresslabel[\lefthyphenmin1000]{\name\\ \street\\ \city}
```

This tells TeX that there must be at least 1000 characters to the left of the hyphenation point.